# An error occurred while worklight installation?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, eclipse-marketplace

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/plugins/com.ibm.imp.worklight.simulation.ui_6.1.0.00-20131219-1900.jar.
Read timed out
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Might be a connection error... try again in 10m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took longer than usual, but I managed to install Worklight Developer Edition from the Eclipse Marketplace in Eclipse Java EE 4.3.1 ("Kepler" SR1).

I think the connection to the repository is just especially slow right now.
There is nothing to do other than waiting and retrying...

Comment: yes connection very slow..thank you for kind support